# Tile 1x2 dominoes in a 2x10 space

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, tiling, dominoes

How many ways are there to tile unmarked 1x2 dominoes in a 2x10 space?

Bonus: What if the dominoes were identical and had pips on their front (face-up), so they could be distinguished by 180 degree rotation?

Comment: How many different types of dominoes are we allowed to use?

Comment: @DanDan0101 which question? Assume the dominoes are indistinguishable.

Comment: Bonus. For instance, I can assume every domino has, say, a 1 and a 2 as the two halves?

Comment: @DanDan0101 yes. You could also consider dominoes that are painted one one side and can be flipped over.

Comment: Amazingly there is closed solution for counting the number of 1x2 domino tilings of any 2D rectangular grid. It has some very deep and complex connections to statistical mechanics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling#Counting_tilings_of_regions

Comment: I'm not surprised since I think any rectangle would have a DP solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

> $89$ ways

Solution:

Suppose that a $2\times N$ space can be tiled in $f(N)$ ways.

> Clearly, $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$. For $N>2$, we can condition on the state of the leftmost domino. If the leftmost domino is vertical, we are left with a $2\times(N-1)$ space to tile, and if the leftmost dominoes are horizontal, we are left with a $2\times(N-2)$ space to tile. Hence, our recurrence relation is $f(N)=f(N-1)+f(N-2)$. From the initial conditions, we see $\boxed{f(N)=F_{N+1}}$, where $F_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number.

Bonus:

> There are $N$ dominoes, and each has two configurations. Accounting for flips, the total arrangements is $2^Nf(N)=2^NF_{N+1}$. In the case $N=10$, this is $91136$ ways.

Bonus, alternate solution:

Suppose that a $2\times N$ space can be tiled in $g(N)$ ways with identical painted dominoes. We proceed as before.

> Clearly, $g(1)=2$ and $g(2)=8$. Condition on the state of the leftmost domino. If it is vertical, it could be in state $\uparrow$ or $\downarrow$. If it is horizontal, the two leftmost dominoes could be in state $\uparrow\uparrow$, $\uparrow\downarrow$, $\downarrow\uparrow$, and $\downarrow\downarrow$. Our new recurrence is $g(N)=2g(N-1)+4g(N-2)$. A simple proof by strong induction suffices to show that $g(N)=2^Nf(N)$.

Proof:

> The base cases are trivial, $g(1)=2=2^1f(1)$ and $g(2)=8=2^2f(2)$. Make the inductive hypothesis that $g(N)=2^Nf(N)$. Now, $$\begin{align}g(N+1)&=2g(N)+4g(N-1)\\&=2\cdot2^Nf(N)+4\cdot2^{N-1}f(N-1)\\&=2^{N+1}(f(N)+f(N-1))\\&=2^{N+1}f(N+1)\end{align}$$
>  $\blacksquare$

Comment: Well done! I'll have to make my counting problems harder.

Comment: The idea of the bonus was to find a different recurrence, but your method works as well.

Comment: @qwr I've added the recurrence!